# Mock/Fake a Repository (or populate a FormMap without persistFormMap)

Tags: java, unit-testing, hippocms

I'm writing unit tests for components of HippoCMS, however I am unable to solve how to fake a Repository object for mocking persistFormMap data.

I followed the basic HST-2 forms suggestion to actually retrieve request data, (http://www.onehippo.org/library/concepts/component-development/hst-2-forms.html), however I haven't found an easy way to mock/fake the Repository section of getWritableSession (called from persistFormMap()) to put into a fake component manager.

`public static Session getWritableSession() throws RepositoryException {
if (HstServices.isAvailable()) {
      Credentials defaultCredentials =                        HstServices.getComponentManager().getComponent(Credentials.class.getName() + ".writable");
      Repository repository = HstServices.getComponentManager().getComponent(Repository.class.getName());
      Session session = null;
      if (repository != null) {
            if (defaultCredentials != null) {
                  session = repository.login(defaultCredentials);
            } else {
                  session = repository.login();
            }
      }
      return session;
}`

Is there a way to get submitted data without persistFormMap()? Or a way of properly faking the repo (Hopefully not something that I've simply looked over in the documentation).

Answer (score 2):

In the setup method of your test suite you can set a component manger
 HstServices.setComponentManager(componentManager)
Make sure componentmanager is a mock. Now you can control what it returns. This may require a bit of mocking, which is unfortunate.

Make sure to set component manager to null in your teardown as it is a static class and may cause problems in tests in the same suite.

Comment: Hey jasper, I appreciate the answer!

Unfortunately, I've already setup a MockComponentManager() and the problem is that I can't add a Repository component to the MockComponentManager as it returns null at the "if (repository != null) {" line in getWritableSession.

Comment: What is your test framework? If you are using the MockComponentManager class you need to add a repository to the components. You could also use mocks from whatever test framework you are using. In mockito, for example, you just need to annotate with @Mock. Or any combination.

Comment: Hey Jasper, Apologies it took a while to reply... In the end I just simply went with Mockito as it makes everything infinitely easier to mock (statically as well) so essentially I'm only testing the stuff thats mine and not CMSHippos! Thanks for the reply as it helped!